# How to query users and group them in age range using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to query users and group them by age range

This is what I have done so far

```
User::applicant()->get()
                ->groupBy(function ($item) {
                    return Carbon::parse($item->dob)->age;
                })
                ->map(function ($collection) {

                    return $collection->count();
                });
```

This is what I have got from above query

[image]

Now want to fetch collection and order by age range

```
18-24: 1,
25-35: 5,
36-45: 89,
46+ : 84
```

Comment: Do you have specific age ranges you want?

Comment: Is there also 0-18?

Comment: Yes I have edited my question @thisiskelvin

Comment: No there is 0-18 because this is recruiting agency site we don't expect applicants to be below 18

Comment: To be clear, this is for the count of people in those age groups, and not for the actual people to be grouped together?

Comment: Yes I want just number of people in those ranges for analytics purposes @thisiskelvin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna use a combnination of [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) and [`mapToGroups()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-maptogroups), I'm pretty sure there must be a simpler way, but this was fun to me:

```php
$ranges = [ // the start of each age-range.
    '18-24' => 18,
    '25-35' => 25,
    '36-45' => 36,
    '46+' => 46
];

$output = User::applicant()
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($user) use ($ranges) {
        $age = Carbon::parse($user->dob)->age;
        foreach($ranges as $key => $breakpoint)
        {
            if ($breakpoint >= $age)
            {
                $user->range = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $user;
    })
    ->mapToGroups(function ($user, $key) {
        return [$user->range => $user];
    })
    ->map(function ($group) {
        return count($group);
    })
    ->sortKeys();

dd($output);
```

The idea behind this is to add an attribute to each record with the value correspondant to their age range, then group them by this key creating a set of arrays of users grouped by range, to finally count the elements for each subarray inside this key.

This should return something like:

> ```php
> => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2948
>      all: [
>        "25-35" => 1,
>        "36-45" => 2,
>        "46+" => 1,
>      ],
>    }
> ```

Comment: I want consolidate them in range like 25-46 => 5 @HCK

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine as you can see at the top of my post, I specified a set of age breakpoints, if you want a range of `25-46` just include: `[ ..., 25, 47, ... ]` in the `$ranges` array.

Comment: Btw, I forgot to sort the keys, fixed in response.

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine I've updated my answer to return your expected output.

Comment: @HCK Didnt know about `->mapToGroups()`. Nice to know

Comment: @thisiskelvin yeah, the `Collection` class has some really interesting methods. That's why this kind of question catch my attention, they are little puzzles to solve. Adam Watham has a nice course (Refactoring to Collections, if I'm not wrong) when he uses this library, Haven't seen it but it has great reviews.

Comment: @HCK Read the pdf! Very good, still need to revisit a few parts.

Comment: @thisiskelvin didn't know there was a PDF. I'll definitely see it now ;)

Comment: @HCK Added you on twitter btw

Comment: Thanks alot guys for your help @HCK

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine glad to help. Have a nice day

Comment: What if the table has like 100k records? You are doing ->get() which will fetch all the records in memory.

Comment: @Abhishek of course in the example I did it in a simple way but the issue you highlight is real if yo uhave thousands of records (memory-wise). For that case, you could make use of cursors/iterators now supported natively using the LazyCollection class. Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#cursors).

Comment: @KennyHorna yup. I would suggest you should add that in your answer as well. At least just the warning.

Answer (score 5):

This is a untested solution (which will need refactoring:

```
$groups = ['18-24' =>, '25-35', ..., '45'];

$applicants = User::applicant()->get();

$groups = collect($groups)
    ->map(function ($range, $key) use ($applicants) {
        $rangeLimits = explode('-', $range);

        $count = $applicants->filter(function ($applicant, $key) use ($rangeLimits) {
            $age = Carbon::parse($applicant->dob)->age;

            $verdict = $age >= $rangeLimits[0];

            if (isset($rangeLimits[1])) {
                $verdict = $age <= $rangeLimits[1];
            }

            return $verdict
        })->count();

        $range = ! isset($rangeLimits[1]) ? $range . '+' : $range;

        return [ $range => $count ]; 
    })->flatten()->all();
```

First you need to create an array of groups which you need, the last group should not have a `+`.

You then get all the applicants.

Then, you loop through each group, and find out if applicants are within its range, and get the count. This is mapped to the resulting array.

Comment: Thank you @thisisKelvin but I query failed because of variable $max do I have to initialize it to 0?

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine Updated, should have been `$rangeLimits[1]`,

Comment: Thanks alot @thisiskelvin

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$users =  \DB::table('users')
      ->select(DB::raw('concat(10*floor(age/10), \'-\', 10*floor(age/10) + 9) as `range`, count(*) as `numberofusers`'))
      ->groupBy('range')
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example using laravel collections:

```
$users = Users::applicant()->get('birth_date')
    ->map(fn ($user) => Carbon::parse($user->birth_date)->age);

$partitions = [
    '-18' => $users->sum(fn ($age) => $age <= 18),
    '18-27' => $users->sum(fn ($age) => $age > 18 && $age <= 27),
    '28-65' => $users->sum(fn ($age) => $age > 27 && $age <= 65),
    '65+' => $users->sum(fn ($age) => $age > 65)
];
```